# SIGSEGV error while inserting in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

Ive gone through some of the previous posts on Stack Overflow before posting this.
Everytime I try to run this on ideone.com (which uses the SPOJ engine) I get a SIGSEGV runtime error and I am stumped.
Can anyone please help me out? Ive commented the line where I *think* I might have gone wrong..

```
//MY CODE TO INSERT INTO A LINKED LIST
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
int data;
struct Node *link;
};
struct Node *node =NULL; //suspected error..not sure

void insert(int item)
{
if(node==NULL)
{
       node->data=item;
       node->link=NULL;
}
else 
{
    struct Node *temp;
    temp=node->link;
    node->data=item;
    node->link=temp;
}
} 

void display()
{
if(node==NULL)
    cout<<"Linked list is empty!";
while(node!=NULL)
{
    cout<<node->data<<" ";
    node=node->link;
}
}         
int main()
{
int n;
    cin>>n;
    display();
    insert(n);

      display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not even close to right. The `display()` function "forgets" where the original start of the linked list is, your code for `insert()` dereferences a pointer after you've JUST FINISHED confirming that it's NULL. Please Google for a working example of a simple linked list implementation and start from there.

Comment: Or better still, grab a book and start reading

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @Celada.Shall work on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating memory to the Node. You need to do this in your insert function:

```
node = new Node();
```

And only after that, you should start filling out `data` and `link` in your node. Do this in both `if` and `else` cases.

The corrected code will be something like the following (I haven't run it through a compiler, so check for compiler errors):

```
void insert(int item)
{
if(node==NULL)
{
       node = new Node();
       node->data=item;
       node->link=NULL;
}
else 
{
    struct Node *temp = new Node();
    temp=node->link;
    node->data=item;
    node->link=temp;
}
}
```

You also need to delete all the allocated nodes later on after you have finished working with the list, otherwise, it will be a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are never allocating the memory for the new `Node`s you are creating.